Pagination in Wordpress is not working, second page loads wrong template
I have problems with my pagination. On the first page 5 posts are correctly displayed on the correct template archive-buch.php and also the pagination button, the next page is empty and a wrong template, index.php is loaded.
The existing posts for this problem have not helped me.
I am grateful for any help.
First here my screenshots:


Here ist my archive-buch.php
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
// Anzahl der Posts pro Seite
$posts_per_page = 5;  // Anzahl der Beiträge pro Seite
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  // Aktuelle Seite

/*
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; } */


// WP_Query für den Buch-Post-Typ
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'buch',   // Custom Post Type „buch“
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,   // Anzahl der Bücher pro Seite
    'paged' => $paged,       // Aktuelle Seite setzen
    'offset' => $posts_per_page * ($paged - 1)
);

// Neue Abfrage erstellen
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Debugging - Query überprüfen
/*
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $query );
echo '</pre>';
*/

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Ausgabe des Buch-Titels und Inhalts -->
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div><?php the_excerpt(); // Ausgabe des Auszugs ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
        // Vorherige Seite (Link zur vorherigen Seite anzeigen)
        previous_posts_link( '« Vorherige Seite' );

        // Nächste Seite (Link zur nächsten Seite anzeigen)
        next_posts_link( 'Nächste Seite »', $query->max_num_pages );
        ?>
    </div>

<?php else : ?>
    <p>Keine Bücher gefunden.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
// Reset der Query-Daten
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <p>&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> - Alle Rechte vorbehalten.</p>
</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

And here part of my functions.php
function create_buch_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'label'             => 'Bücher',
        'public'            => true,
        'has_archive'       => true, // Stellt sicher, dass ein Archiv vorhanden ist
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'buecher' ),  // Rewrite-URL korrekt setzen
        'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'buch', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_buch_post_type' );

Any help is appreciated

Check this link for using paginate links function for prev and next links for custom post type
Here is your modified code as per above reffrence link
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
// Anzahl der Posts pro Seite
$posts_per_page = 5;  // Anzahl der Beiträge pro Seite
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  // Aktuelle Seite

// WP_Query für den Buch-Post-Typ
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'buch',   // Custom Post Type „buch“
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,   // Anzahl der Bücher pro Seite
    'paged' => $paged,       // Aktuelle Seite setzen
);

// Neue Abfrage erstellen
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Ausgabe des Buch-Titels und Inhalts -->
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div><?php the_excerpt(); // Ausgabe des Auszugs ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
        // Previous and Next Links with WP_Query
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $paged,
            'prev_text' => '« Vorherige Seite',
            'next_text' => 'Nächste Seite »',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div>

<?php else : ?>
    <p>Keine Bücher gefunden.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
// Reset der Query-Daten
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <p>&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> - Alle Rechte vorbehalten.</p>
</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

